# How to minimize .htaccess rules?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a following `.htaccess` rules for seo friendly url :

**.htaccess rules :**

```
Options -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/aponit/dev/not-found.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/aponit/dev/404.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?:zones/)?update/(\w+)/?$ zones/update.php?z=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:cable-types/)?update/(\w+)/?$ cable-types/update.php?cbl=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Now, using this rules I can access following url :

```
http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/update/63
http://localhost/aponit/dev/cable-types/update/3
```

Now I have to create this type of url many more! So is there anyway in this `.htaccess` rules to minimize the rules ?

**I mean** if I need 10 different url I have to add 10 rules to the `.htaccess` file. e.g:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:another/)?another-f/(\w+)/?$ another/another-f.php?another-id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I want one rules in this`.htaccess` file for this type of url.

**Update:**

In index.php file under zones folder I have following code to edit and add new data :

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="<?php echo SITE_URL."zones/update/$zone_id"?>" >Edit</a> 

<h4 class="panel-title pull-right"><a href="<?php echo SITE_URL.'zones/add' ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Zones</a></h4>
```

To edit the form data I need this type of url :

```
http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/update/63
```

Too add data I need this type of url :

```
http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/add
```

and finally in .htaccess rules I need only one rules to follow this type of  urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these two generic rules instead of above type of rules:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/aponit/dev/$1/$2\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/$2.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/aponit/dev/$1/$2\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/$2.php?q=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Please note that name of the GET parameter will be same `q` for all such URLs. Inside `.php` file you can use `$_GET['q']` to read it.

Comment: `zones` is a folder. In this folder I have 3 files : index.php, update.php, add.php

Comment: `http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/add` this url showing error message.

Comment: No URL you should try: `http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/update/63` as that is what you wrote in question

Comment: My earlier .htaccess rules was access to both url but not using your one !

Comment: You are not seeing something obvious. Both your rules have `update/` in the pattern. Now explain how those rules match `http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/add`?

Comment: Are you going to argument with me or can you please answer my questions. If you can't then you are most welcome. No problem for me.

Comment: I surely intend to answer and that's why I am spending my time. But you are saying something that I don't understand so I am asking a simple question how that rule is working for you when URL is `http://localhost/aponit/dev/zones/add`?

Comment: Great, but this url showing error message : http://localhost/aponit/dev/cable-types/udpate/3. Note: there are a `hyphen ( - )` in the url

Answer (score 0):

Just use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(\w+)$  /$1/$2.php?z=$3  [QSA,L,NC]
```

It will rewrite:

```
zones/update/63      >>  /zones/update.php?z=63
cable-types/update/3 >>  /cable-types/update.php?z=63
```

Note 1: This standardizes your paths. You no longer make the first part (`zones/` vs `cable-types/` optional)

Note 2: that you have to standardize the name of your first query parameter. I use `z` above.  Then, within the PHP files, you use it as needed.  The `cable-types/update.php` will use it just as you used the `cbl` parameter before

Comment: Using your rules, I got error message : Object not found!